# gcc10->12: My operator<<(ostream, mytpe) isn't recognized anymore

Tags: c++, gcc

I have some code that works well in gcc10 (debian bullseye):

```
#include <vector>
#include <filesystem>
#include <slib/logmacros.h> // template <class T> void LogVerbose(T content);

using namespace slib;

using Paths=std::vector<std::filesystem::path>;
inline std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &p_stream, const Paths &p_paths)
{
    std::string sep;
    for(const auto &p: p_paths)
    {
        p_stream << sep <<  p;
        sep = ",\n";
    }
    return p_stream;
}

namespace internal {

std::string BusinessLogic(Paths& p_paths)
{
    return slib::stringutils::Format("Paths are: %1", p_paths);
}

} // namespace
```

In GCC10, this worked great, but in GCC12 (debian bookworm), I get the following error:

> error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::stringstream’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream’} and ‘const std::vectorstd::filesystem::__cxx11::path’

`Format()` is a function that will ultimately should call that operator.  This code below isn't anything I have control over, but can raise bugs if it's something in there.

```
namespace slib {
namespace stringutils {

template <class TData>
void DoParameterReplace(std::stringstream& p_stream, std::string& p_format, unsigned p_index, const TData& p_to,  std::string::size_type &p_from_pos)
{
    p_stream.str("");       // makes result empty but keeps manipulators
    p_stream << p_to;
    // manipulators are functions
    DoParameterReplace(p_format, p_index, p_stream.str(), p_from_pos, std::is_function<TData>::value);
}

template <typename ... TParams>
std::string Format( std::string p_format, TParams && ... p_params )
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string::size_type from_pos = 0u;
    unsigned index = 0;
    // C++17 comma fold
    ((DoParameterReplace(ss, p_format, index++, p_params, from_pos)),...);
    (void)index;        // otherwise gives I think incorrect warning error: variable ‘index’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
    (void)from_pos; // same
    return p_format;
}

} // namespace
} // namespace
```

I'm not sure why gcc now fails to find the operator overload.

I tried:

1. changing `ostream& operator<<(ostream& , ... )` to `stringstream& operator<<(stringstream& ...)`
2. Placing my `operator<<` in `namespace slib { namespace stringutils {}}`
3. Placing my `operator<<` in `namespace internal {}`

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: is the macro actually relevant for the error? If yes please include it in the quesiton. If not you can simply call `ToString` directly to see the error

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai  good question.  Will update.

Comment: Probably running into ADL, which won't look in your `operator<<` namespace (i.e., the *global* namespace) because both left- and right-hand parameters are in the `std` namespace, in some scenarios (such as interop with templates).  (The `using` doesn't change that.)

Comment: generally it is not recommended to overload operators for type you don't own. As the call is already wrapped inside a macro inside another function, how about a named function? `print(p_stream,p_to)` ?

Comment: Ah, okay.  So the trick is to either to put this in `namespace std` or avoid using that operator and define my own function to unpack this.

Comment: fwiw, I can see the error with gcc12 but I didnt manage to get it to compile with gcc10

Comment: no. You cannot put it in `std`, thats not allowed

Comment: I can confirm that putting this in `namespace std` solves the problem, but exposes a design issue.  Will implement a function without `operator<<`.  Thanks

Comment: you made a typo somewhere https://godbolt.org/z/srKojxM83

Comment: btw if you dont have constrol over `DoParameterReplace` and it does require a `<<` then the solution would be to not use a `std::vector`. You could use a `struct my_type { std::vector<....  };` and supply an `<<` for that

Comment: Oh, I like that idea.  Instead of `using Paths=std::vector<std::filesystem::path>`, and instead of encapsulation I might be able to reduce the amount of code that requires changing with `class Paths : public std::vector<std::filesystem::path> { using std::vector<std::filesystem::path>::vector; };`

Comment: inheriting from `std` type is not recommended either (and usually ends in tears)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old GCC behavior was a long-standing bug that has been fixed with GCC 12, see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51577.

The lookup for a dependent operator should only consider overloads that are visible at the point of definition via usual unqualified lookup and via ADL at the point of instantiation. However GCC, non-conforming to the standard, also did usual unqualified lookup from the point of instantiation.

Your code seems to rely on the fact that this bug is present, because your `operator<<` overload is not declared in a namespace scope in which it could be found by ADL.

You can't reliably overload an operator for types if these types do not depend on one of your own types. In particular you can't add a stream output for `std::vector<std::fileysystem::path>`, which contains no type that belongs to you. (In particular adding the overload to the `std` namespace, which would give the intended ADL behavior according to the core language, is not permitted by the standard library rules.)

You could derive a type from either `std::vector<std::fileysystem::path>` or just `std::fileysystem::path`  (whether by inheritance or composition) and then declare the overload in the same namespace scope as that type for it. Then the overload can be found via ADL if the argument is your derived type (or a `std::vector` of your derived type).

---

The old GCC behavior is somewhat dangerous. It makes it much easier to accidentally violate ODR because now the some extra `operator<<` declaration in one translation unit may cause a template specialization instantiation in that translation unit to use that overload, while an instantiation of the same specialization in another translation unit may use a different one. The lookup rules prevent such mistakes as long as the operator overloads are always declared together with the type that they overload for in the same namespace and header file.

Comment: Got good MCVE to prove your point: https://godbolt.org/z/bjzjWE6b7 It also proves that other way to fix this is to change order (but IMO this is fragile fix).